# Packages availability on Anaconda upgrade

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, anaconda, cloudera

We are having an older version of Anaconda downloaded as a parcel on our Hadoop cloudera cluster and wanted to upgrade it to lastest verison. In the older version, by default, we didn't find packages tensorflow, geopandas, noaa_sdk, thrift_sasl, gensim and few other which are required for our data science use case. We have installed them manually across the cluster.

My question would be, if I upgrade Anaconda, will the packages be available which are manually installed? Or do I have to install them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you installed Anaconda on hadoop nodes using Cloudera parcels?

https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/partner/anaconda.html

If yes, then you're correct, you'd have to reinstall everything you installed on top of hadoop nodes.

Cloudera looks at parcels as "[immutable](https://github.com/cloudera/cm_ext/wiki/The-parcel-format#cloudera-manager-assumptions)" - their state shouldn't change. So when you install something on top of parcels, or change them in any way, expect you changes can be lost. (e.g. parcel redeployment, as it'll untar the parcels again) Same applies for upgrades - new Anaconda version comes with just a new tar file (that's what a parcel basically is, with some metadata information).

If you're interested in managing Python environments - look at `conda` virtual environment - https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/overview.html

, or `conda-pack` specifically as an example for Spark on YARN - https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/spark.html

We're currently migrating all of our Spark jobs to `conda` environments, instead of relying on Anaconda parcels.

PS. I noticed you're using `python-2.7` tag for this topic. Notice that free Anaconda Cloudera parcels (starting with Anaconda 5 release) no longer provide `Python2`. It'll come with `Python3` there. Beware! That change brought us off guard. And that was another reason to migrate to `conda` as we can switch between `Python2` and `Python3` now easily by project.

Comment: Does Anaconda provide CDH parcel with Python 3.x that is free (as in community edition)? Is Anaconda 5.2 parcel free as well?  Everywhere I read, the docs say it's enterprise version other than the freely available one with Python 2.7.x

Comment: They actually recently switched to Python 3. Check for example Anaconda 5.3 or their most recent 2019.03 release with the new versioning scheme yyyy.mm is also Python 3 based. So we started building two parcels ourselves. One for Python 2 and another for Python 3.